# Запрос Update MySQL C# datagridView in column?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике на любую строку велось автоматически значение в ячейку столбца и чтоб это значение введенное отобразилось и в БД, но получается только вставить в форму datagridView значение но не обновить таблицу БД.
Помогите плиз разобраться!!
Вот код, который я реализовал:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f = new Form3();
        int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Update transportation set active = @active where idtransportation=@id", conn);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[7].Value = "X");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Value = "X"` вы до сих пор не исправили ошибку

Comment: какая ошибка? ошибок нету я не могу обновленное значение ячейки datagridview обновить в БД

Comment: Разницу между `=` и `==` знаете?

Comment: равенство и сравнение это знаю применяю в условиях сравнение

Comment: так я ж не сравниваю содержит ли она определенный  символ я хочу его вести и чтоб не я это делал и программа за меня это делала поэтому и написал Value = "X" хотя я могу ошибаться и есть другой способ ввести программно значение и обновить

Comment: ок, значит я не понял, зачем вы в поле "@active" пишете "X" и какого оно типа в базе.

Comment: Ну я прописал к ячейке значение X, а эту ячейку прописал в @active, в базе данных она текстовая Varchar

Comment: у меня получается только datagrid заполнить но не обновить БД с обновленной ячейкой вот в чем проблема или это так нельзя и невозможно реализовать задуманное мной?

Comment: К сожалению, мне непонятен вопрос, код выглядит нелогично, задача не ясна. Нужно больше деталей. Как вы поняли, что не получается обновить таблицу? Ошибка возникает? Какая? Какую задачу решаете, зачем всё это? Что такое button3? Почему используете current а не selected строку dgv? Вы отлаживали код, уверены, что `row` получает правильное значение?

Comment: я понял что не обновляется смотря в свою бд программы MySql Workbench. Свойство CurentCell использую чтоб получать активную строку. Повторюсь - моя задача как-то при клике на строку вывести значение ячейки в определенном мне столбце, а этот столбец datagridview.Rows[row].Cells[7] чтоб в 7 ячейке при опред. id вывел это "X" button3 это кнопка где срабатывает весь этот код. Никаких ошибок не возникало. Хотя я не считаю себя профессионалом в этом спорить с вами не буду как лучше должно быть но поэтому со своим опытом и знаниями я не знаю что еще нужно.

Comment: так что вы посоветуете мне сделать я уже почти все перепробовал не знаю что делать?